# Netbeans and EOF

Tags: java, netbeans, antlr, antlr3, eof

Java, ANTLR and Netbeans newbie here.

I have installed a jdk and netbeans.  I started a new project on netbeans 6.8 and i have added the antlr-3.2.jar as a library.  I also created a lexer and parser class using AntlrWorks.  These classes are named ExprParser.java and ExprLexer.java.  I copied them into a directory named path-to-netbeans-project/src/parsers.

I have a main file:

```
package javaapplication2;

import org.antlr.runtime.*;
import parsers.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(System.in);
        ExprLexer lexer = new ExprLexer(input);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        ExprParser parser = new ExprParser(tokens);
        parser.prog();

    }

}
```

The application builds fine.  The book I'm reading says I should run the program and type in some stuff and then press Ctrl+Z (I'm on windows) to send EOF to the console.  Problem is that nothing happens when I press Ctrl+z in the netbeans console.  When I run from the command line, ctrl+z works fine.

This is probably WAY too much information, but I can't figure it out.  Sorry.  Probably not a good idea to learn 3 new technologies at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(System.in);
```

you could just do:

```
ANTLRStringStream input = new ANTLRStringStream(args[0]);
```

where `args[0]` is the first command line parameter.

Or just:

```
ANTLRStringStream input = new ANTLRStringStream("your source here");
```